# Dart: How to bind to variables annotated with int via Web UI?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

What is the best practice in Dart when dealing with classes as data records?

To Elaborate: When writing an app, it is likely that a class for a table row will be created.  As in

```dart
    class Item {  int itemid, String itemName, double score   }
    Item item = new Item();
```

This allows compile time catching of any typos etc. in Dart. (Unlike using a class that relies on NoSuchMethod.)

It will also need a corresponding string structure to bind to the HTML such as

```HTML
    <input id="itemname" type="text" bind-value="itemEdit.itemName">
```

So the Dart would be:

```dart
    class ItemEdit { String itemId, String itemName, String score }
    ItemEdit itemEdit = new ItemEdit();
```

Next we need a way to get from one to the other, so we add a method to Item

```dart
    fromStrings(ItemEdit ie) {
      itemid = ie.itemId == null ? null : int.parse(ie.itemId);
      itemName = ie.ItemName;
      score = ie.score == null ? null : double.parse(ie.score);
    }
```

And the other way around:

```dart
    toStrings(ItemEdit ie) {
      ie.itemid = itemId == null ? '' : ie.itemId.toString();
      ie. itemName = itemName == null ? '' : itemname; // Web_ui objects to nulls
      ie.score = score == null ? null : score.toStringAsFixed(2);
    }
```

Also, we get jason data from a database, so we need to add another method to Item:

```dart
    fromJson(final String j) {
      Map v = JSON.parse(j);
      itemid = v['itemid']; 
      itemname = v['itemname'];
      score = v['score'];
    }
```

And we need to be able to revert to default values:

```dart
    setDefaults() { itemId = 0; itemName = "New item"; score = 0; }
```

This verbosity gets me feeling like I am writing COBOL again!

There is something fundamental missing here - either in my understanding, or in the Dart/WebUI libraries.

What I would like to write is something like

```dart
    class Item extends DataRecord {
      int itemid = 0,
      String itemName = 'New item',
      double score = 0.0;
    }
```

Then, without further coding, to be able to write code such as

```dart
    item.toStrings();
    ...
    item.fromStrings();
    ...
    item.fromJson(json);
    ...
    item.setDefaults(); // results in {0,'New item',0.0}
```

And to be able to write in the HTML:

```HTML
    value="{{item.strings.score}}"
```

If this was possible, it would be quicker, simpler, clearer, and less error prone than the code I am writing at the moment.

Comment: See [Dart Issue 8000](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=8000)

Answer (score 0):

(Full disclosure, this answer is written with the assumption that at least one bug will be fixed. See below)

Three suggestions that might help.

1. Use named constructors to parse and create objects.
2. Take advantage of toJson() when encoding to JSON.
3. Use bind-value-as-number from Web UI

1) Named constructors

```
import 'dart:json' as json;

class Item {
  int itemid;
  String itemName;
  double score;

  Item.fromJson(String json) {
    Map data = json.parse(json);
    itemid = data['itemid'];
    itemName = data['itemName'];
    score = data['score'];
  }
}
```

2) Encoding to JSON

The `dart:json` library has a `stringify` function to turn an object into a JSON string. If the algorithm encounters an object that is not a string, null, number, boolean, or collection of those, it will call toJson() on that object and expect something that is JSON-encodable.

```
class Item {
  int itemid;
  String itemName;
  double score;

  Map toJson() {
    return {'itemid':itemid, 'itemName':itemName, 'score':score};
  }
}
```

3) Now, having said that, sounds like you want to easily bind to HTML fields and get primitive values back, not just strings. Try this:

```
<input type="number" min="1" bind-value-as-number="myInt" />
```

(Note, there seems to be a bug with this functionality. See https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/issues/317)
(from https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/web-ui/8JEAA5OxJOc)

Comment: 1) Thats a neat feature, but doesn't cut to the heart of the matter - it also duplicates the field names, inside quotes, what's more.  That is not pretty code.  2) Yes, the json library is nice.  But again, field names are duplcated in your code, again inside quotes. 3) Yes - and no.  That would be very much a second prize to alleviate some of the problem.  What I want is to be able to concisely define a data record, typing in each field name only once, and everything else taken care of.  Batteries included!

Comment: Not sure that the renamed title of this question reflects what it is really about...

Comment: You can try Chris Buckett's JsonObject package, which uses noSuchMethod to handle the parsing for you. See http://www.dartlang.org/articles/json-web-service/ for more info. Until mirrors work in dart2js, I think there will have to be some duplication of code. Or, one can write a code generation library to take care of the boilerplate.

Comment: I renamed the title to make this a bit more specific. I understand you're asking a broad question. Alas, Dart doesn't ship with a full end-to-end completely DRY solution yet. But we can try to make it a bit nicer until then. Feel free to rename the title.

Comment: It seems I do not have the authority/votes to rename a title :(  I think DRY is a crucial feature for a language of the caliber of Dart - is this a specific issue being discussed anywhere, or should I raise it as an issue on code.google.com?

Answer (score 0):

Just found a way to perhaps help a little in the this situation:

```
      class obj {
        int gapX;
        String get gapXStr => gapX.toString();
               set gapXStr(String s) => gapX = int.Parse(s);
      ...
```

Now, from the HTML you can use, for example

```
    bind-value="gapXStr"
```

and in code you can use

```
    x += ob.gapX;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if DART automatically implemented .AsString to work as above for the num class!?